# tkinter doesn't open TopLevel first

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button, command is function. There is 2 functions inside this function.

1. First is with TopLevel with progressbar inside
2. Second with main calc function

.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *

class Sth:
    def __init__(self, main):
        Button(main, text='Start processing!', command=self.go).pack(side=TOP)

    def popup(self):
        t = Toplevel()
        t.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
        self.f = Frame(t)
        self.f.pack()
        Label(self.f, text='Please, wait...').pack()

        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.f, mode="determinate")
        self.pb.pack()

    def go(self):
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.popup())
        p1.start()
        p1.join()
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process())
        p2.start()
        p2.join()

        # self.popup()
        # self.process()

    def process(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.pb['value'] += 20
            print('doing sth')
            time.sleep(0.5)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Tk()
    Sth(main)
    main.mainloop()
```

But func with toplevel & progressbar, which have to open before main calc function opens only after execution. What I did wrong?

Comment: `target=` needs function name without `()` - ie. `target=self.popup`. Now you run `self.popup()` in main thread before you even create class `Process()`

Comment: `.join()` what for end of process - so code after `join()` is executed only when you close window and it ends process.

Comment: when you click button then it doesn't create elements at once but it has to end function and go back to mainloop which will draw all elements in one moment - this way window doesn't flicking on every change. Normally you could use `root.update()` to force mainloop to draw wigets but there is other problem: all GUIs don't like to run part of code in separated thread or process. All GUI should run in main thread

Comment: @furas I removed `()` , what about join, should I remove it for p1 or replace somewhere I do not understand a little

Comment: @furas but if I run everything in one run it will start lagging

Comment: in process you have to run only calculations but GUI has to run in main thread (main process).

Comment: you would have to use queue to send value from calculation to main process and `root.after(millisecond, function)` to run function which will periodically get value from queue and update progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

First: all GUI/widgets (in most GUI frameworks, in most languages) have to run in main thread (main process).

You can run calculations in separated process but `ProgressBar` has to be in main process. You will need `queue` to send data from calculations to main process. And you will need `tkinter.after(milliseconds, function)` to run function which will run periodically check queue and update `ProgressBar` (and it will not block `mainloop`).

---

I run `popup` in main process and it uses `multiprocessing` to run calculation (but without `join()` which blocks all code). It runs also run `update_progressbar` which check if there is new data in queue to update progressbar. it use `after()` to run itself again after 100ms - this way it doesn't block `mainloop`. Ca

I uses `queue.empty()` to check if there is data to get because normally `queue.get()` would wait for data and block code and `mainloop`

I don't uses `p.join()` because it also block code. You could check it when you close program - but I skiped this part.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
#from tkinter import * # not preferred
import tkinter as tk

class Sth:

    def __init__(self, main):
        tk.Button(main, text='Start processing!', command=self.popup).pack(side='top')

    def popup(self):
        self.t = tk.Toplevel()
        self.t.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)

        self.f = tk.Frame(self.t)
        self.f.pack()

        tk.Label(self.f, text='Please, wait...').pack()

        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.f, mode="determinate")
        self.pb.pack()

        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process, args=(self.queue,))
        p.start()
        #p.join() # don't use in this place becaus it blocks all code

        self.update_progressbar()

    def update_progressbar(self):
        if not self.queue.empty(): # without this `get()` will wait for data and it will block code
            self.pb['value'] += self.queue.get()

        if self.pb['value'] < 100:
            self.t.after(100, self.update_progressbar)

    def process(self, q):
        for i in range(10):
            q.put(10)
            print('doing sth')
            time.sleep(.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = tk.Tk()
    Sth(main)
    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: I got an error : EOFError: Ran out of input. I guess that is because of sth in multiprocessing

Comment: code works for me on Linux Mint (after adding some missing `tk.`) so problem has to be different. `EOFError` means `End-Of-File` and it could happen when code is incomplet.